# How do I ensure a build has consistent provenance records so it can run incrementally?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

A transform is building snapshot instead of incremental.
Essentially the same transform is building incrementally in another project.

Foundry gives the reason:

> Provenance records for the previous build are inconsistent

What does this mean? How can I ensure the provenance is consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long-shot: Your incremental transform has multiple outputs, and you are aborting one of your outputs while still writing a transaction to the other(s) ?

If so, you need to abort all output datasets or write to all, but doing it partially is what makes it "inconsistent".

Comment: That was it! And the differences in behaviour were down to scheduling differences between the projects hiding the issue.

It seems calling `write_dataframe` isn't required to get a completed transaction, it's enough to just not abort the output.